# Mysterious forces in d3 force directed layout?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I'm trying to progressively combine two groups of nodes to simulate a sort of adhoc pie chart using a force layout. To do this, I'm using two groups of nodes connected via links to two fixed, animated, foci nodes, respectively. When they combine with ruffly the same number of nodes, the effect works well.

see: http://bl.ocks.org/vicapow/6191895

however, when there's a large difference in the groups of nodes, (say, 1 / 100 ), there seems to be some mysterious extra force applied to the smaller group of nodes away from the larger group

see: http://bl.ocks.org/vicapow/6191896

Does anyone have any ideas on where this extra force could be coming from?

some of the things I've tried that didn't work:
+ forcing the alpha to stay 1 
+ reducing the friction

Comment: First - I don't know anything. With that out of the way: it doesn't really look like a rejection or an extra force. It looks like when you one or two red nodes they are not strong enough to force themselves into the blue dots.

Comment: I was gonna make a similar mention to Kobi -- can you elaborate on what you mean by "mysterious force"? I do feel the first animation seem slower but that is simply because the red nodes and blue nodes need to position themselves separate from each other as opposed to the second animation which simply has one node that steps aside.

Comment: The mysterious force I mentioned was that in the second version with only one red node, it seems to hover a large distance above the blue nodes. This effect isn't observed in the first version and I'm trying to figure out some why to remove it. I'd like the red dot to be bumped up against the blue dots like in the first version. All the nodes have the same spring and charge forces applied to them so I can't think of what else would be causing this behavior.

Comment: update: interestingly, if add link the node to the first foci, the forces seem to be applied properly. it's only when the lonely node is connected to the second foci, that it floats out further than the other nodes on the first foci. [see this example](http://bl.ocks.org/vicapow/6244421)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are seeing is the lack of gravity. Without gravity the nodes will not tend towards the center of the screen. I was able to get the desired result for your edge case by setting `force.gravity(1)` and the charge for the nodes to -100. https://bl.ocks.org/david4096/6264697

Comment: that's simply compressing all the nodes into the center. If I wanted to achieve that effect, I would have linked all the nodes to a single foci. Or better yet, just add all the nodes with gravity, not worrying about linking up the nodes to a single foci. But instead I'm looking to take two groups of nodes and combine them together into one large group of nodes, without this mysterious additional force. And then maybe later, combine those groups of nodes into other groups. Maybe this better demonstrates what I'm getting at. [link](http://bl.ocks.org/vicapow/6265529)

Comment: maybe [this visualization](http://blog.vctr.me/posts/simpsons-paradox.html) does a better job of illustrating why I want to do this in the first place and also shows the artifact in question when the nodes combine at the end of the animation.